# Making Side-By-Side Tables Match Height

Tags: css, mobile, html-table, html-email

Alright, as far as I can tell, the problem I'm posing here is one that doesn't seem to have a solution that's easily Googleable. Perhaps I'm just flubbing my searches and/or not understanding what I'm seeing/doing, but I really haven't been able to find anything.

This is basically the structure of a mobile-friendly email template. To allow all the content to become single-column when viewed on a mobile device, everything needs to be collected into tables. Unfortunately, as we all know, tables don't naturally stretch to the height of their neighbors. They can clearly push down on the content below, but the neighbor can't match it.

Obviously, under normal structures this would be solved by constructing everything as TDs inside of a TR, but the structure I'm showing you is mandatory, and took a long time to become what it is. I don't have much room to be flexible on this (at least as far as my higher-ups go), but if the solution requires some intensive restructuring, I'll definitely try and see how to make it work.

Any input is deeply appreciated, and a solution will be rewarded with a thousand gold Krugerands.

Code sample is below, fuller example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Malachite/FwTxZ/).

```
<!-- CONTENT CLOSE -->              
</td>
<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER CLOSE -->        
</tr>
</table>
<!-- COLUMN CLOSE -->       
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- COLUMN -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; background-color: transparent;">
<tr >
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;  border: 0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px"> 

<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER -->    
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; background-color: #000;">
<tr >

<!-- CONTENT -->
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; margin:0px;">

<!-- CONTENT CLOSE -->              
</td>
<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER CLOSE -->        
</tr>
</table>
<!-- COLUMN CLOSE -->       
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- COLUMN -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  valign="top" style="width: 50%; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: top; clear: left;" align="left">
<tr >
<td  valign="top" style="width: 100%;  border: 0; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px;" > 

<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER -->    
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; background-color: #0e616d; " >
<tr >

<!-- CONTENT -->
<td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; margin:0px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #005c5b;">

<p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 72px;  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #24ccca; font-weight: bold;">LONG</p>
<p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: #fff;">I'm dragging out this sentence so that I can provide a good example that properly illustrates the issue I'm having. I've also upped the font size because I really shouldn't be making this example so elaborate, but I'm kinda having fun.</p>

<!-- CONTENT CLOSE -->              
</td>
<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER CLOSE -->        
</tr>
</table>
<!-- COLUMN CLOSE -->       
</td>
</tr>
</table>




<!-- COLUMN -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  valign="top" style="width: 50%; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: top;   " align="left">
<tr >
<td  valign="top" style="width: 100%;  border: 0; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px;" > 

<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER -->    
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; background-color: #0e616d; " >
<tr >

<!-- CONTENT -->
<td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; margin:0px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #005c5b;">

<p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 72px;  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #24ccca; font-weight: bold;">SHORT</p>

<p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: #fff;">See the column to the left for an explanation for why this column is so dang short.</p>

<!-- CONTENT CLOSE -->              
</td>
<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER CLOSE -->        
</tr>
</table>
<!-- COLUMN CLOSE -->       
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<!-- COLUMN -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; background-color: transparent;">
<tr >
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;  border: 0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px"> 

<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER -->    
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; background-color: #000;">
<tr >

<!-- CONTENT -->
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; margin:0px;">

<!-- CONTENT CLOSE -->              
</td>
<!-- CONTENT WRAPPER CLOSE -->        
</tr>
</table>
<!-- COLUMN CLOSE -->       
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: What's the overall objective?  Is it to have the backgrounds for each table in a row the same height?  Since this is an email table, you cannot rely on javascript to achieve this.  You might end up having to predefine the heights based on your content.

Comment: Nathan: Sadly, no. Would if I could, but this is for emails, otherwise I'd have this problem all sewn up.

Comment: Axel: The dark blue area that contains the content needs to match the height of its neighbors. I wish I could predefine heights, but it's made for users to add and edit content as they please, and since our users are going to be laymen...yeah. That's why I'm pretty stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your making email template. If I'm right, the best solution is to create proper table, so rather than nest table inside table try to work it out with single table with colspans and rowspans:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>cell</td>
    <td colspan=2>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And some css:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
td {
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}

table table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
table table td {
  width: 33%;
}
```

You just need to style it right and it should be fine.

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Benjh)

Update:
Well, maybe it;s not exatcly single table, but it has proper construction.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answer, and our previous version was actually exactly like this. The issue is that we're working to make our emails mobile-friendly, and the structure you see here is what makes it work. (Turning all table widths to 100% creates a single-column layout that's easier for people to read on their phones). So I'm stuck using this side-by-side nested table structure.

Comment: And why you assume that this structure isn't mobile friendly? It's all based on %.

Comment: It's because I need the structure to detect that it's at a certain resolution (let's say 480px wide), then make all multi-column content structures 100% width, creating a single-column structure. Unless there's something I'm missing, I can't make that happen with the standard table structure. :(

Comment: Oh, ok. I see it now. I hope you are aware, that writing an email template has one general rule: code it like it's '97. :)

Comment: I'm painfully, painfully aware. :) We're just ambitious, and I think we're on the verge of perfection here, it's just this one...last...thing...